# Firefox renders CSS incorrectly (spacing varies)

Tags: html, css, concrete5

Currently I am using Concrete5 to build a website, located here: http://tinyurl.com/cee5rvo

Firefox pushes the header (navigation and h1 tag) down on certain pages (such as Gallery) and I have no idea why.

Chrome and IE10 both display correctly.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what is your css and html? have you tried, top:0; padding, margin 0?
Maybe put it in a jsfiddle to show your problem

Comment: Which version of FF are you using? Can't see anything such on my FF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to add a line to your #content div.

```
#content {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 800px;
}
```

The overflow hidden will clear the floats and stop the undesired effect of pushing the content down.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can't test it out yet as my computer is packed away, but will try both solutions mentioned when I have the chance

Comment: good luck with the move!

Comment: Thank you, I'm not actually moving but heading home from Uni for summer

Answer (score 0):

You have a 10px margin on the div #asmillerGalleryBlock... set this to margin: 0 auto;

Comment: Ah yes, that is there because I was attempting to fix the issue by manually aligning them according to which page they were on. Then I realised that it was only Firefox so I removed all those hacks, accidentally leaving that one in.

Answer (score 0):

Your elements aren't taking up space correctly due to float issues.
add this to your css:
    #content {float:left}

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is to do with how you're floating elements.

If you inspect `nav-selected nav-path-selected` in your nav, you'll see it's computed height is 0px.

This is a very common issue caused by floating elements not forcing their parent containers to resize automatically. When an element is floated, its parent no longer contains it because the float is removed from the flow. As browsers handle this problem in different ways, a common solution is to use a 'clearfix'.

If you add the following to your global css...

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}



html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

And add the clearfix to elements with 0px height (e.g. nav-selected), you'll see the element inherits the correct height.